# How to send data together with the file?

Tags: java, php

**Hi.**

**My problem:** I can send a file, but I also need to send together some data that I will receive in my **PHP** **scirpt** through `$_POST[]`, but I do not receive them. Sent the file and data from a **Java program** and are received by a script on my server. For now I am only sending a single data together to the file.

This is my full load method:

```
public void upload(File file) throws Exception {
        URLConnection conn = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://mandaos2019.000webhostapp.com/CONECTOR.php");
            System.out.println("url:" + url);
            conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);



            String postData = "";

            InputStream imgIs = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] imgData = new byte[imgIs.available()];
            imgIs.read(imgData);

            String message1 = "";
            message1 += "-----------------------------4664151417711" + CrLf;
            message1 += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test_8.jpg\""
                    + CrLf;
            message1 += "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + CrLf;
            message1 += CrLf;


            // the image is sent between the messages in the multipart message.

            String message2 = "";
            message2 += CrLf + "-----------------------------4664151417711--"
                    + CrLf;

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711");
            // might not need to specify the content-length when sending chunked
            // data.
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf((message1
                    .length() + message2.length() + imgData.length)));

            System.out.println("open os");
            os = conn.getOutputStream();

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            ps.print("&proyecto=" + "prueba");

            System.out.println(message1);
            os.write(message1.getBytes());
            // SEND THE IMAGE
            int index = 0;
            int size = 1024;
            do {
                System.out.println("write:" + index);
                if ((index + size) > imgData.length) {
                    size = imgData.length - index;
                }
                os.write(imgData, index, size);
                index += size;
            } while (index < imgData.length);
            System.out.println("written:" + index);

            System.out.println(message2);
            os.write(message2.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            System.out.println("open is");
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            char buff = 512;
            int len;
            byte[] data = new byte[buff];
            do {
                System.out.println("READ");
                len = is.read(data);

                if (len > 0) {
                    System.out.println(new String(data, 0, len));
                }
            } while (len > 0);
            System.out.println(conn);
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Close connection");
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }
```

This fraction is responsible for sending the data together:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());
ps.print("&proyecto=" + "prueba");
```

I should be able to send this little **value** to the **script** on my server.

My code in my **PHP script** is to receive the file and then upload it to **Firebase Storage**, but it requires the value of `$_POST["proyecto"]` to be able to create a directory in the **Storage** by **project**.

```
$target_path = "uploads/"; 

        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

        $name =  $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 

            $myfile = fopen($target_path, "r")  ;

            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 

            $this->bucket->upload($myfile, [
                'name' => $_POST["proyecto"] . "/" . $name
            ]);

        } else{ 
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
        }
```

**Thank you** and I look forward to your support.

Comment: What does `$_REQUEST` say? Btw, do you really need `$_POST["proyecto"]` - because its value is hardcoded in your java?

Comment: Not really all I need is to be able to pass that data (projects) together with the file